# How to cast a vector of shared_ptrs of a derived class to a vector of share_ptrs of a base class

Tags: c++, stl

```
class Interface
{
};

class Class : public Interface
{
};

class Foo
{
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Interface>>& GetInterfaces()
    {
        return *(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Interface>>*)(&m_data);
        //return m_data;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Class>> m_data;
};
```

This works but is ugly and scary. **Is there a better/safer way to do it?** I don't want to make `m_data` of type `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Interface>>` because the module `Foo` belongs to works entirely with `Class`'s, `Interface` (and `Foo::GetInterfaces()`) are implemented to interact with a separate module that should only know about the `Interface` functionality.

Let me know if anything here is unclear, it makes sense to me but I've been banging my head against the problem for a while.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Casting is not correct, they are distinct types; I am pretty certain you are invoking undefined behaviour.

You need to construct a new vector and return it by value.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Interface>> b (m_data.begin(), m_data.end());
return b;
```

This should still be fairly cheap (1 allocation).

Comment: What's the shared pointer going to do in that situation? I'm not sure it's going to want to share pointers between two different types of shared pointer!

Comment: @MichaelKohne no this is fine.

Comment: Ahh, move semantics for the win! should make returning by value ok.

Comment: @111111 - what makes that OK? You can't assign shared pointers of different types (even if they are base and child classes) with any compiler I have handy, so I don't understand how this can work. I don't have the latest compilers, so it may just be something I don't know.

Comment: @111111, just to make sure I'm not missing anything, there's still going to be a linear time copy, right? (when constructing b)

Comment: @MarcosMarin as far as I know; but it's only copying pointers, so unless the data set is HUGE then the allocation should dwarf the copying.

Comment: @MarcosMarin by the way, if you are uisng C++11 you can simplify it to `return { m_data.begin(), m_data.end() };`

Answer (score 5):

Besides that this is not possible with the implementation of `vector`, the issue is also that references don't convert. Your code is even worse and is undefined behavior.

What you can do is provide an interface that exposes a range or `begin/end` instead of the container itself. If you combine that with a `transform_iterator` that does the conversion, you should be set.

Sample code:

```
class Interface {
  virtual ~Interface();
};

class X : public Interface {};

class C {

private:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<Interface> iptr_type;
  typedef std::shared_ptr<Class> ptr_type;
  std::vector<ptr_type> v_;

  struct F {
    iptr_type 
    operator()(ptr_type p) { return iptr_type(p); }
  };

  typedef boost::transform_iterator<
    F, std::vector<ptr_type>::iterator> iiterator;

public:
  iiterator
  begin()
  { 
    return boost::make_transform_iterator(
      begin(v_), F()); 
  }

  iiterator
  end()
  { 
    return boost::make_transform_iterator(
      end(v_), F());
  }
};
```

Comment: If it makes sense in your use case then exposing a `.begin()` and `.end()` iterator interface is a good option.

Comment: @111111 Sure, that as well. But I guess ranges are the more hip thing.

Comment: my comment was one in support of your idea :)